# The execution order of the code when using jsonp with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am using jsonp with jQuery and it is working well. But the execution order of the code is not what I expect. I mean I have a function as:

```
function is_server_alive() {
    var result;
    console.log("beginning of function result" + result);
    $.ajax({
        url: server + "/is_alive",
        async: false, 
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function(JSON){
            result = JSON.return;
            console.log("is_server_alive result: " + result);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("server is dead " + textStatus);
        },
    });
    console.log("end of function result: " + result);
    return result;
}
```

I try to return the result variable. But because of the ajax request after all the thing happen I can't do that. The returned value seem undefined. The console output like:

```
beginning of function result: undefined
end of function result: undefined
is_server_alive result: 0
```

I try async for both true/false and nothing changed. How can I return the result variable or change the execution order so the output become:

```
beginning of function result: undefined
is_server_alive result: 0
end of function result: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another setting, `complete`, to the `$.ajax` function:

```
function is_server_alive() {
    var result;
    console.log("beginning of function result" + result);
    $.ajax({
        url         : server + "/is_alive",
        async       : false, 
        dataType    : "jsonp",
        jsonp       : "callback",
        success     : function(JSON){
            result  = JSON.return;
            console.log("is_server_alive result: " + result);
        },
        error       : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("server is dead " + textStatus);
        },
        complete    : funciton () {
            console.log("end of function result: " + result);
            return result;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: But does `return result;` in the complete handler will actually act as a return for `is_server_alive` ?

Comment: This only change the console output but not the execution order. Still the ajax request executed after everthing else.